# Trying to populate a label with text entered by a user in a repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, textbox, repeater

I'm trying to populate labels on a repeater from what a user enters in a text box. However, the value entered in the text box isn't being picked up so nothing happens when I click the button that is to dispplay the text in the labels.

My VB code is here:

```
Protected Sub cmdShowCost_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdShowCost.Click
    rptProducts.DataBind()
    Dim someString As String
    Dim txtField As TextBox
    Dim lblField As Label
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    For Each item In rptProducts.Items
        txtField = CType(item.FindControl("txtAmountToBuy"), TextBox)
        lblField = CType(item.FindControl("lblCost"), Label)
        If Not IsNothing(txtField) Then
            j = j + 1
            someString = txtField.Text
            lblField.Text = someString
        Else
            lblField.Text = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

and my html is here:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server" >
                   <HeaderTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Product Name
                             </td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Price per Kg
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Kg in Stock
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Action
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Amount to Buy
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Cost
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%#Eval("Product")%>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%#Eval("PricePerKg")%>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%#Eval("QuantityKg")%>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href='amount.aspx?ProductID=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID")%>&Stock=<%#Eval("QuantityKg")%>'>Details...</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmountToBuy" runat="server"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCost" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
</div>
```

The rest of the repeater works fine, it's just the populating the labels that doesn't work.
This is my first time posting a question, hopefully someone can help. I searched as best I could for this problem but nothing seemed to work.

Thanks.

Comment: So if you debug, is txtField being set? ie, did it find txtAmountToBuy?

Comment: Any reason why you rebind the repeater on cmdShowCost click event?

Comment: +1 @ajakblackgoat - It will work fine if OP remove the line `rptProducts.DataBind()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two thing you need to take care of:

1.In page_Load you need to make sure that you are not binding the repeater in PostBack:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        rptProducts.DataSource = GetProducts() 'Or whatever datasource you have
        rptProducts.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

2.In click method of the cmdShowCost button, don't bind the repeater (As mentioned by [ajakblackgoat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2264365/ajakblackgoat) ) :

```
Protected Sub cmdShowCost_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdShowCost.Click
    'rptProducts.DataBind()
    Dim someString As String
    Dim txtField As TextBox
    Dim lblField As Label
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    For Each item In rptProducts.Items
        txtField = CType(item.FindControl("txtAmountToBuy"), TextBox)
        lblField = CType(item.FindControl("lblCost"), Label)
        If Not IsNothing(txtField) Then
            j = j + 1
            someString = txtField.Text
            lblField.Text = someString
        Else
            lblField.Text = 0
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't get back to this - I was expecting to get notifications in my e-mail so didn't realise this had been aswered.. Believe it or not I ended up solving it myself, using pretty much the solution suggested by afzalulh. Thanks again.